# jquery animation on div innerhtml on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="outerDiv"><img src="1.png" /></div>
```

I want to change the innerhtml of outerDiv to another image,

**Can I have some animation/fadein-fadeout effect in the code below using jquery?** or any other way to change inner html with animation.

```
$('#outerDiv').html('<img src = "2.png" />')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#outerDiv img').fadeOut(1000, function()
{     
    $(this).attr('src',"2.png").fadeIn(1000);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hvG7k/